# A confusing error in spyder “Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects”

Tags: pandas

I have a example run in spyder.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
                     'D': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
                     'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
                    index=[2, 3, 6, 7])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                        'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                        'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                        'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                        index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1,join='inner')
```

however ,when I want to view the “result” by Double-clicking it in variable explorer. There is a error for me in internal console.
[image]

[image]

the vesion of my Spyder is as follow,
[image]

I want to know why.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce with Spyder 3.0.0.

Comment: @ ayhan,I see,maybe the problem is caused by the bug in Spyder.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from the duplicate column names. Change the name in one dataframe and this error should disappear.